# Excel - X-axis issues when combining x-y scatter and column charts

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to superimpose a column chart on an x-y scatter chart. I have done that by adding a series (for the column chart), creating a new y-axis for the values, etc. However, the x-axes don't work out. The x-y scatter data are clearly plotted as numerical data; but the column chart is plotted as categories. I can set a secondary x-axis, but it's still categories so that doesn't help.

I have seen answers where data are manipulated to "force" the category data to line up. I cannot do this as I have >10 series, and each series has 3000 - 8000 data points (but my column data has about 30 data points).

Can I plot the "column" data as an x-y scatter plot and somehow format it to look like columns instead of markers and a line?

See image showing column with x-value wrong:

[image: Plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities to get the appearance you've described:

1) As you noted (but dismissed), you can "force" the category to line up.  You'll need to line your column chart data to match their equivalent XY series X data.  You'll end up with 8000 column data points (all categorical, but matching your X data), with lots of #N/A entries to prevent errant data from being plotted as a column.

2) You could also plot the column data as a separate XY series, and use a formatted Y Error bar to represent your column.  This is far easier than option #1 above, but the formatting options are somewhat limited compared to a true column chart.

In the image below, the Blue columns are based upon Option 1 above, while the Red columns are based upon Option 2 above.

[image: XY with Columns]

Comment: Thank you. Option 1 doesn't work for me as each series I have has a different # of data points and they are not "lined up" (that is, Series 1 may have 3000 data points starting at time = 0 and with 10 minute increments; Series 2 may have 6789 data points starting at time = 213 minutes and with varying intervals). However, Option 2 does work - limited options, but it gets the job done!

Comment: I'm upvoting option 2, which I use all the time. I sometimes use option 1, but it's not as flexible and harder to set up.